# with "s" or without "s"

Tags: clauses, subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural

> There is a sharp spherical boundary **differentiate** the occupied and
>   unoccupied states.

I wrote the above sentence, and check it in "WriteSmoke" software to see whether it is correct or not. The software gave a positive response and told me the sentence is correct. However I felt strange and thought that the "differentiate" should be "differentiates". So I modified the sentence and let the software to check it again. Surprisingly, it still told me the sentence is right!!

So with "s" or without "s"? Are both situations right?

Comment: Neither. Don't use software to check English grammar. Software is not ready for English grammar yet. It's wrong. The sentence is ungrammatical. You should not use **either** an infinitive _differentiate_, **or** a 3rd person present singular _differentiates_, but rather an active participle _differentiating_.

Comment: @ John: If the sentence starts with there is, a subjective relative pronoun can be omitted.

Comment: @JohnLawler According to the comments, Rathony and Henry have different opinions. I am a little confused, which to believe. Could you please say something?

Comment: @Rathony: I have no idea where you got that idea. Subjects don't get deleted from tensed clauses except by rule, and this is not a part of the rule of _There_-Insertion. Perhaps it's a local English; but it's ungrammatical in American English. Henry is correct.

Comment: @John. Let me have your e-mail address. I am not a creator of any Grammar Rule. I am just a follower like yourself. You need to argue with the writer, not me. Your face will turn red definitely, though.

Comment: @Rathony Hi, Rathony! You seems to have a strong proof to your statement. Would you mind to show me the page of your book? My e-mail is balabi@qq.com

Comment: @user15964 Your English seems to have a big problem. You shouldn't use seems after You, you shouldn't use to show after mind. I will send it to you, though.

Comment: @Rathony: You mistake me for somebody else; I'm not a follower of anybody's "rules".; I'm one of the people who discover the rules and tell people about them. And your supposed authority is, I'm sorry to have to tell you, incorrect. False information from so-called grammar authorities a very common thing, really. Everybody wants to have an authority to back them up, and since every grammatical opinion has vociferous supporters, it's easy to find authorities that agree with one's own ideas.

Comment: @John. It is your call. I am not sure how you can discover the rules without reading a grammar book, and also if you are competent enough to stop the trend. I will see. If you haven't heard people saying "There is noun (without relative pronoun) verb structure", you got to be non-native.

Comment: @Rathony He **writes** the grammar books. The feature you're (probably) talking about is restricted to a few dialects of mostly British English, and it is always associated with less formal speech; for example, “There's a guy here says you ordered pizza” is grammatical in _some_ dialects, but ungrammatical in most.

Comment: @Janus How many dialects do you speak and understand? I am very curious.

Comment: @Rathony Speak? Three or four. Understand, recognise, and have knowledge of? About 20 or so, at a guess.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet is “There's a guy here who says that you ordered a pizza.” is this correct?

Comment: @Usernew Yes, absolutely correct.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two grammatically correct ways to write it:

> There is a sharp boundary **differentiating** the occupied and unoccupied states.
>
> A sharp boundary **differentiates** the occupied and unoccupied states.

In the first version, you need a present participle, because the sentence's verb is "is", not "differentiate". In the second version, the verb is "differentiate", so it needs to be conjugated to agree with "sharp boundary".